# Why didn't Jessica Atreides have a son and a daughter?

Tags: dune

In the novel Dune,  Jessica Atreides had been ordered to have a daughter with Duke Leto.  However; she defied that order and had a son as Leto desired.  As is well know, a woman can have multiple children. Why then didn't Jessica have a son and a daughter? Everyone would have been happy.

Comment: Considering all the many different problems which the gazillions of people in the iperium had, I doubt whether "everyone would have been happy" all the time.